# Order source dataframe, store id column in output dataframe

Tags: r, loops, sorting

I have a dataframe approximately 80x300. It looks like this:

```
id          var1     var2     var3     ...
Alpha       23       68       22
Bravo       29       48       37
Hotel       39       10       85
...
```

My goal is to get an output data frame which has the same columns as the source data frame, but instead of the values it has the name of the id value in rank order. It should look something like this (id would be dropped as unnecessary upon completion)

```
id          var1     var2     var3
            Hotel    Alpha    Hotel
            Bravo    Bravo    Bravo
            Alpha    Hotel    Alpha
```

I have attempted to do this in the following way:

```
rank <- read.csv()
out <- rank[0,]  # to create output data frame with exact same columns as source

for (i in 1:ncol(rank)) {
  order(rank[i])  # sort source dataframe by i'th column
  out[i] <- rank$id_column  # store id_column (after re-ranking) as i'th column in output dataframe
}
```

When I run `order(rank[i])` it appears to work fine, but when I run the loop I either get no result or an error:

> replacement has X rows, data has 0

I would like to use this method of looping through the columns in this way but I'm open to other options. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I know I may also have to worry about ascending or descending later so if anyone can touch on that it'd be great but I can figure that part out after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
apply(df[,-1], 2, function(x) df$id[order(x)])
# var1    var2    var3   
# [1,] "Alpha" "Hotel" "Alpha"
# [2,] "Bravo" "Bravo" "Bravo"
# [3,] "Hotel" "Alpha" "Hotel"
```

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text="
id,var1,var2,var3
Alpha,23,68,22
Bravo,29,48,37
Hotel,39,10,85
", header=T, sep=',', stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: I see you want reverse order, then use -x

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by looping over the columns, get the `rank` and use that to subset the 'ID'

```
data.frame(lapply(df1[-1], function(x) df1$id[rank(-x)]))
```

Or with `order`

```
data.frame(lapply(df1[-1], function(x) df1$id[order(-x)]))
#   var1  var2  var3
#1 Hotel Alpha Hotel
#2 Bravo Bravo Bravo
#3 Alpha Hotel Alpha
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `mapply`

```
# Dummy data
df = data.frame(id=c("Alpha", "Bravo", "Hotel"),
                var1=c(23, 29, 39),
                var2=c(68, 48, 10),
                var3=c(22, 37, 85))

# Sorting function
sorting_hat = function(i){
   df$id[order(i, decreasing=T)]
}

# Your "loop"
df_new = mapply(sorting_hat, df[, -1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try to run it I get this error "Error in rank[, -1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". Do you have any idea what the problem could be? I tried removing the part to drop the first column but still get the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I'd put the decreasing argument in the wrong place!